# Drupal. Get path alias from current url without the installation's folder arguments

Tags: drupal, drupal-path-aliases

I'd like to retrieve the current page path alias without the installation's folder arguments.
I'm using:

```
drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri())
```

But this returns installation/whatever/**actual/path** and I want to retrieve the *actual/path* only no matter what *installation/whatever* is.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it. It was actually a mix of both suggestions:

```
$current_path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["q"]);
```

Thanks though.

---

**Update: the previous solution doesn't always work**

Someone suggested using an alternative method:

```
str_replace(base_path(), '', drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri(), 1));
```

**But, is there any way of doing the same without using the slightly expensive str_replace?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The path of the node you are on?

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_path_alias/6

```
if ($node || (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(2) != 'edit')) {
   $system_path = 'node/'.arg(1);
   $current_path = drupal_get_path_alias($system_path);
}
```

That code will fire on node pages and tell you the page alias.

For more information, you can dump out $_GET and look at the 'q' query string value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use base_path() and str_replace like this :

```
str_replace (base_path(), '', drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri()), 1);
```

The base_path is saved in the database.

Comment: This also does the trick for any kind of page if it wasn't for the typo.

Fixed version is:
str_replace(base_path(), '', drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri(), 1));

Comment: My intention was finding a way of doing this without str_replace. Any ideas?

Comment: why you add an argument to drupal_get _path_alias?

Comment: To retrieve the current URL, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$current_page_url = drupal_get_path_alias( implode( '/', arg() ) );
```

also works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$_GET['q']`?

Comment: That returns the path, not the alias. Thanks though, I already found it.

Comment: Enable the Global Redirect module and the path should always be that of the alias.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @netcoder You can consider the answer "try $_GET['q']", then. You really are bumping a two year old thread for this?

Comment: @ceejayoz: No, it's the review tool that posts comments automatically. Clearing up the flagged answers, and this should probably have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to plump for the full url instead to avoid any problems that arise when base_path() isn't just '/'.

```
$url = (($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?"https://":"http://")  .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . url($_GET['q']);
```

or even more simply:

```
$url = url($_GET['q'], array('absolute'=>true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest solution.

`substr(drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri(), 1), strlen(base_path()));`

To pass it into an argument

`$arg = explode('/', substr(drupal_get_path_alias(request_uri(), 1), strlen(base_path())));`